# How can I get my function, which uses another function as argument to work?

Tags: python, function

For an assignment I have to make a function that calculates the forward derivative of an input function and then make sure it works by running it on `sin(x)`.
I tried to make it like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ForwardDer(f(x),h=0.1):
    FDer = (f(x*+h)-f(x*))/h
    return FDer
```

And to test this code I ran:

```py
ExampleSin = ForwardDer(math.sin(5))
print(ExampleSin)
```

This gave me a syntax error so after some googling I adjusted my code to the following.

```py
def ForwardDer(f,x*,h=0.1):
    FDer = (f(x*+h)-f(x*))/h
    return FDer

ExampleSin = ForwardDer(math.sin(),5)
print(ExampleSin)
```

This complains that `math.sin` has too few arguments but using `(math.sin(5))` as an argument also doesn't work. Can anybody explain to me how I can succesfully call a function like this in another function? I really don't get it.

Comment: I added code formatting to your question. Please take some time to fix the indenting. Also add the full error message you are getting.

Comment: `math.sin` is the name of the function.  Anything with parentheses after that would be an attempt to call the function.

Comment: You need to pass a function, not call it `ForwardDer(math.sin, 5)`

Comment: Also `x*` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: what is `x*` suppose to be? That should give you a syntax error as well.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass function, method, class or any other callable as argument, you don't want to call it with `()`.

Do not use `*` in variable name. It's special character.

It's also a good practice to name functions/methods/variables with `snake_case` and classes with `CamelCase` *(Read: [Naming Conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions))*.

I refactored your code a bit, check it out:

```py
import math

def forward_der(func: callable, arg: float, h: float = 0.1) -> float:
    return (func(arg + h) - func(arg)) / h


example_sin = forward_der(math.sin, 5)
print(example_sin)
```

It prints to console:

```
0.33109592335406
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I now see I mean to type * x instead of x * although I doubt it would have helped much. I now see that my biggest problem was not realizing that I shouldn't have tried to call a function with (). 

May I ask why you added things like : callable and : float to the function? Doesn't python notice this automatically?

Also, my apologies for the initial formatting. I tried to make it nice but that didn't work out so well.

Comment: Callabale and float is type hint. Typing in python is optional, but it's very usefull. It's does not effect code directly and would not change anything in logic/interpreting, but gives Python IDE like Pycharm or VSC information about desired type. Later on, when you would try to pass integer argument to function that expects string type, you will be instantly noticed about this, even before running (and crashing) your code. 
I strongly recommend you to use Pycharm community IDE. It's free, popular and will help you with formatting by pep8 suggestions.